# Broke my volume knob on my Yamaha Pacifica

Tags: guitar, repair

So I was changing my volume pod on my guitar (Yamaha RGX 121 ZL) and I've so far gotten as far as taking off the volume knob knob thingy. I wanted to make sure that I knew what I was doing, so I attempted to put it back on. It just kinda slipped on, it doesn't have the same feel to it when I turn it.

How can I fix this? Do I also need a new cap now?

Answer (score 3):

Typically volume knobs have one of two types of fixings, one with a small grub screw that tightens into the side of the shaft, and one that just uses friction. Check on the side of the knob - if there is a screw, like these ones on [axesrus.com](http://www.axesrus.com/Knobs/Metal/Tele/Metal/SetScrew/Domed/SetScrewDomedTeleKnobs.jpg), you can just tighten that up to make it sit securely on the shaft again.

[image]

If there isn't a screw, and the knob is loose, you have a couple of options. I would typically go for a very small dot of cyanoacrylate glue. This will hold the knob to the shaft, but when you need to remove it, you can lever it off with a screwdriver. An alternative is to use something like PTFE tape around the shaft to thicken it enough that the knob grips it.